# Scala higher order function compiler error

Tags: scala

I am learning Scala apply and higher order function. I have this coding, but why compiler gave me an error: "missing parameter type", how to fix it ?

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

object MyArr {
  var mList1 = ListBuffer[Int]()

  def filter(p: Int => Boolean): List[Int] = {
    val mList = List[Int]()
    for (x <- mList1) {
      if (p(x)) x :: mList
    }
    mList
  }

  def apply(x: Array[Int]) = {
    for (y <- x) mList1 += y
  }
}

def isEven(x: Int): Boolean = {
  x % 2 == 0
}

var mCustomArr = MyArr(Array(1, 2, 3, 4))
mCustomArr.filter(x => isEven(x)).foreach(println)
```

if apply method just takes a single parameter and add it to mList1 , it will work. why ?

thanks

Comment: Take a look at your apply function.  It doesn't work the way you think it does.

Comment: Try to avoid `var` and such mutability, that doesn't correspond to Scala philosophy

Comment: @cchantep, you are right, will modify.

Comment: why down vote my question?. isn't it a good practice and help lots of newbie ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had added the return type to the `apply()` definition the compiler would have pointed out exactly where the error is.

```
def apply(x: Array[Int]): ListBuffer[Int] = {
  for (y <- x) mList1 += y
  mList1
}
```

Comment: thanks, you are right. but why it will work without return type if apply method takes a single parameter

Comment: All methods have a return type, regardless of the parameters. Parameters are immaterial to this issue. If you specify the expected return type, the compiler will tell you if the code doesn't produce it. If you don't specify the expected return type, the compiler will assume that whatever the code produces is correct for that method.

Answer (score 0):

In the apply method, it updates mList1 in Object and return Unit. So variable mCustomArr will be Unit type.

If you want to use filter method, you need to use MyArr Object like `MyArr.filter(x => isEven(x)).foreach(println)`.

But when I look into your implementation of filter method, it looks like mList inside method never changed. I think the filter method could be implemented like

```
object MyArr {
  var mList1 = ListBuffer[Int]()

  def filter(p: Int => Boolean): ListBuffer[Int] = {
    val mList = ListBuffer[Int]()
    for (x <- mList1) {
      if (p(x)) mList += x
    }
    mList
  }

  def apply(x: Array[Int]) = {
    for (y <- x) mList1 += y
  }
}
```

Hope you happy to learn Scala, Cheers.

Comment: thanks, please see my updates in the end. so I don't think it is mCustomArr issue.